# Upgrading some code to build on VS2013 from VS2008 "error C3865: '__thiscall' : can only be used on native member"

Tags: c++, windows, hook

I have some code which "works" in VS2008 in that it will build and run and do what I expect. However I have a build error in VS2013, I've managed to reproduce it with just this code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <vector>

template < class T >
class SignatureScanner
{
public:
    SignatureScanner(const BYTE* aPattern, const char* aMask, int aExpectedMatches = 1, int aOffSetToFuncStart = 0)
    {
    }

    const std::vector<T> Funcs() const
    {
        return iFuncs;
    }
private:
    std::vector<T> iFuncs;
};

// Workaround/hack to define a thiscall function
static void __fastcall fake_this_call_func(void *thisPtr, void* not_used_hack, int aParam)
{
    printf("this [%x] param [%d]\n", thisPtr, aParam);
}

// type_traits(396): error C3865: '__thiscall' : can only be used on native member functions
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    typedef void(__thiscall* myFuncPtr)(int thisPtr, int aParam);

    // I use this in some hook code to find a function and redirect it to fake_this_call_func
    // which works when it builds
    SignatureScanner< myFuncPtr > p(0, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

I want to know why did 2008 not have an error when 2013 does, and how should I go about resolving this error? It only needs to build for Windows XP 32-bit - so platform specific hacks are OK.

Comment: Hmya, C++11 happened in between, it added std::is_member_object_pointer.  The added compiler support for the type trait is none too happy about you faking a member function pointer like that.

Comment: Is there a workaround to please it? :) The MSDN docs for this error don't make any sense in the context that I've managed to create it in.

Comment: Removing __thiscall is the workaround.  That's probably about as helpful as your question was in explaining why you need to do this.

Comment: I'm hooking the member function of a class, I figured it didn't matter as to why.

Comment: Looks like the code in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11048176/detouring-a-member-function-via-an-injected-dll will build - I'll try to figure it out from that